# React expo error log is splitted by letters

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm new in react, sorry for noob question ...
Something happens with error log. It was normal, readable and usefull. But in one moment it's getting like on screenshots. Someone knows what's affects on log output? Thanks.

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khrXl.jpg)

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqFwp.jpg)

It's react expo app on iPhone.

Comment: Looks like your bundle has release mode, not debug. How do you start your project?

Comment: -- expo start in console

Comment: @E.Dn Yes, it's a production. It's normal for production mode?

Comment: Yes, it's normal for production mode. Try to switch to development mode and it should work ok.

Comment: Please check if you have called any component in lowercase in your files

Comment: @E.Dn Thanks! Everything OK in development mode!

Comment: @Davit Tchkoidze Your welcome! Please, check my answer below as "right" then to get your question answered:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is your expo is running in production mode (buildling release bundle). To get rid of that just switch to development (debug) mode.